# Change owner of a sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, owner, usergroups

My company has recently started sharepoint for collaboration. Now I created sites and subsites for all my projects. And that time I created new groups for owner, members and visitors for each subsite. But later I realised that the owner group can be same for all subsites. So I deleted the owner groups for 2 of my sites. Now I am unable to create subsites or delete those sites. How do I find who is the owner and how can I add myself as the owner for these sites. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the `/_layouts/permsetup.aspx` page on each of the sites to add the new owner group.

For instance, if you had a site with the url `http://testapp/testsite/`, you would go to `http://testapp/testsite/_layouts/permsetup.aspx`

Comment: I am getting an Access denied message for this